# Python-samba causing failed apt-get calls

Tags: apt, samba

Recently re-booted my fileserver and found it would not boot. I'm currently in recovery mode for the previous kernel `3.13.0-62-generic` on 14.04.

When i run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`, or `sudo apt-get install -f`, I get the following error:

```
austin@FSERV:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-samba (2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 524, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 408, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depends on python-samba; however:
  Package python-samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on python-samba; however:
  Package python-samba is not configured yet.
 samba depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9); however:
  Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
 winbind depends on samba (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9); however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-winbind:amd64:
 libnss-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9); however:
  Package winbind is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-winbind:amd64:
 libpam-winbind:amd64 depends on winbind (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.9); however:
  Package winbind is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-samba
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 winbind
 libnss-winbind:amd64
 libpam-winbind:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
austin@FSERV:~$
```

I'm planning to re-install the kernel that is causing a boot failure, but can't do because of this python error. Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `python-samba` configuration script is (eventually) trying to import `_sysconfigdata_nd` module, but it can't find it.

There was an [Ubuntu package bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466) that caused exactly that. But it was in early 2013, and you report that you use 14.04, so your packages shouldn't be affected.

Start by running `dpkg -S _sysconfigdata_nd.py` to verify that this file is indeed installed. If it is not, then you might try reinstalling `libpython2.7-minimal` package. If it is, run `python` and type `import sys; print sys.path` to get a list of directories where python will look for modules. I guess that directory where `_sysconfigdata_nd.py` is is not on that list.

If it isn't you might try one of workarounds posted in mentioned bug report: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.py /usr/lib/python2.7/` or `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`.

It is also possible that your multiarch configuration is broken, but this could only happen if you have modified it sometime in the past.